# Symfony4 "object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation" 404 error

Tags: symfony4

I discover Symfony4 with similar blog sample like describe in https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html
Then I added a new route to add /blog/about page. So a part of code in my *src/Controller/BlogController.php* is:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}", name="blog_show")
 */
public function show(Description $article) {
    return $this->render('blog/show.html.twig', [
        'article' => $article,
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("blog/about", name="about")
 */
public function about() {
    return $this->render('blog/about.html.twig', [
        'copyright' => "GLPI 3",
    ]);
}
```

and when I run locahost:8000/blog/about, it returns me a 404 error :
*App\Entity\Description **object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation***

Comment: Just do a simple installation: 

``` composer require annotations ```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you add a requirement to the route, then the order doesn't matter.

eg.

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}", name="blog_show", requirements={"id":"\d+"})
 */
```

The requirement is a regex.

Answer (score 31):

After hours to find solution, I finally read https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html and understand that the ***/blog/{id}*** annotation **catch** */blog/about* route but can't use it!

By switching functions order in my controller file:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/about", name="blog_about")
 */
public function about() {
    return $this->render('blog/about.html.twig', [
        'copyright' => "GLPI 3",
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}", name="blog_show")
 */
public function show(Description $article) {
    return $this->render('blog/show.html.twig', [
        'article' => $article,
    ]);
}
```

It works fine !

**The solution as mentionned by @tom is the only one with severals entities and controllers !**

Comment: it could help to use php bin/console debug:router or php bin/console router:match <path> (replace <path> by your path, "/about" in my sample

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have the same Method which is **GET**

Therefore, the first reached path is **/blog/about** and "**about**" is interpreted as an **ID** which not the case !

So the easiest way to solve this is to switch functions order:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/about", name="blog_about")
 */
public function about() {
    return $this->render('blog/about.html.twig', [
        'copyright' => "GLPI 3",
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}", name="blog_show")
 */
public function show(Description $article) {
    return $this->render('blog/show.html.twig', [
        'article' => $article,
    ]);
}
```